# Multiple Condition variable calling each other function

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue, condition-variable

I came across tutorial [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#boundedbuffer) Bounding Buffer example. For reference i am also pasting it here.

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
   #include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
   #include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>
   #include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
   #include <boost/call_traits.hpp>
   #include <boost/progress.hpp>
   #include <boost/bind.hpp>

   template <class T>
   class bounded_buffer {
   public:

      typedef boost::circular_buffer<T> container_type;
      typedef typename container_type::size_type size_type;
      typedef typename container_type::value_type value_type;
      typedef typename boost::call_traits<value_type>::param_type param_type;

      explicit bounded_buffer(size_type capacity) : m_unread(0), m_container(capacity) {}

      void push_front(boost::call_traits<value_type>::param_type item) {
         // param_type represents the "best" way to pass a parameter of type value_type to a method

         boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
         m_not_full.wait(lock, boost::bind(&bounded_buffer<value_type>::is_not_full, this));
         m_container.push_front(item);
         ++m_unread;
         lock.unlock();
         m_not_empty.notify_one();
      }

      void pop_back(value_type* pItem) {
         boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
         m_not_empty.wait(lock, boost::bind(&bounded_buffer<value_type>::is_not_empty, this));
         *pItem = m_container[--m_unread];
         lock.unlock();
         m_not_full.notify_one();
      }

   private:
      bounded_buffer(const bounded_buffer&);              // Disabled copy constructor
      bounded_buffer& operator = (const bounded_buffer&); // Disabled assign operator

      bool is_not_empty() const { return m_unread > 0; }
      bool is_not_full() const { return m_unread < m_container.capacity(); }

      size_type m_unread;
      container_type m_container;
      boost::mutex m_mutex;
      boost::condition m_not_empty;
      boost::condition m_not_full;
   };
```

When I try to push the first element(push_front). " push_front()" function reaches condition variable and and goes to wait until it receives a notification once it receives the notification it gonna check function "is_not_full()" and then proceed. But since it's the first element trying to be pushed, it will never receives the notification since the function "pop_back()" will not complete the execution because the buffer is empty.

Am I thinking it correctly ?  can i able to ever push element to this piece of code ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation for boost::condition? Because that isn't how I'd write a condition wait loop manually, and it isn't how the predicate behaves in `std::condition_variable` either ...

Comment: @Useless Read the question properly. That code comes _from_ the Boost documentation.

Comment: OP claims it will wait for a notification before calling `is_not_full`. I'm asking if that's really how it behaves, because the standard condvar loop is `while(!pred) wait()`, ie, I'd expect `is_not_full` to be called before waiting for a signal that may never come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to push the first element(push_front). " push_front()" function reaches condition variable and and goes to wait until it receives a notification [...]

This is false. Read [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_condition.html#idm45963399270880-bb) of this API carefully. What you describe is the behavior of

```
template<typename L> void wait(L & lock);
```

which is number 3 in the list of public member functions. However, the call to `wait` in your code has **two** arguments; your code calls

```
template<typename L, typename Pr> void wait(L & lock, Pr pred);
```

which is number 4 in that list. This function is documented as being the same as

```
while ( !pred() )
    wait(lock);  // <-- This is where the thread waits for a notification
```

That is, the predicate is checked first, and only if it is false will the thread wait until a notification is received. As long as an empty buffer is not full, the predicate will be initially true, so execution proceeds without waiting for a notification. (However, if you were to construct a buffer with a capacity of zero, then this does look like it will hang when trying to push the first element into the buffer.)

Comment: Thanks..I have check in c++ link too: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait/. It is mentioned "If pred is specified (2), the function only blocks if pred returns false".